# How can I calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} f\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)$ using matrix calculus?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} f\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)$ where $\vec{x}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ which is applied element-wise. Is it correct that since both $\vec{x}$ and $f\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)$ are vectors the partial derivative must be a Jacobian matrix? I tried applying the chain rule and various identities I have found on Wikipedia, but I am very unsure about the result:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} f\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{x}} \left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)\operatorname{diag}\left(f'\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)\right) = A\operatorname{diag}\left(f'\left(A\vec{x} + \vec{b}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in Jacobian form:

$\frac{\delta (f_i)}{\delta(x_j)}(Ax+b) * A = Jf(Ax+b)*A$

where $f(x_1,...,x_n) = (f_1(x_1,...,x_n),...f_n(x_1,...,x_n))$

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you have a specific function in mind, for which you know the derivative,
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{df(z)}{dz} &= g(z) \cr
 df &= g\,dz \cr
}$$
When this function is applied element-wise to a vector argument, 
the Hadamard ($\circ$) Product must be used in the differential 
$$\eqalign{
 df &= g\circ dz \cr
}$$
For this problem, define 
$$\eqalign{
  z &=  Ax + b \cr
 dz &=  A\,dx \cr
}$$ 
then the differential of your function is 
$$\eqalign{
 df &= g\circ dz \cr
    &= G\,dz \cr
    &= GA\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= GA \cr
}$$
where the matrix 
$\,G = {\rm Diag}(g)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a Jacobian matrix. When I get confused with vectors/tensors ("was there a transpose?"), I always start writing down a couple of components and then try to infer what the general expression is.

If you tried but still can't figure it out, read further. Let's compute the derivative of the $i$-th component of $f$ with respect of the $j$-th componente of $x$. To do this, don't forget that every component of $Ax+b$ depends on $x_j$, so we need to use the chain rule $n$ times.

$$
\partial_{x_j}(f_i(Ax+b)) =\\
(\partial_{x_1}f_i)(Ax+b)\cdot \partial_{x_j}(Ax+b)_1+\cdots+(\partial_{x_n}f_i)(Ax+b)\cdot \partial_{x_j}(Ax+b)_n\\
=(\partial_{x_1}f_i)(Ax+b)\cdot \partial_{x_j}a_{1j}+\cdots+(\partial_{x_n}f_i)(Ax+b)\cdot \partial_{x_j}a_{nj}\\
=(\nabla f_i)(Ax+b)\cdot a_j
$$
where $a_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. So how does this read when we put all the components together? The entry $J_{ij}$ of the Jacobian is what we just computed. Well, $J_{ij}$ is the product of the $i$-th row of $J_f$ with the $j$-th column of $A$. Therefore, denoting products with $*$ to not confuse with function evaluation,
$$
J_{f(Ax+b)} = J_f(Ax+b)*A.
$$

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x}$?

If we use the definition
$$
\frac{\partial g }{\partial \vec x}(\vec a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+h \vec x)-g(a)}{h},
$$
(for a function $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$), then the usual rules of limits should give the answer $A$.